# CEF - undesired trembling effect for animations ( font awesome)

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, chromium-embedded

I'm fairly new to CEF (Chromium Embedded Framework ), AppJS, node-webkit. I am trying to compile a desktop standalone HTML application.. 
I noticed that font-awesome animation does not render properly and there's a trembling effect for fonts and animations.. e.g loader spinner ect..

Comment: Which render artifacts do you experience? Because if it's shake/wobble there is a [specific issue which you can resolve](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/671) adding `-webkit-filter: blur(0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how this fixed the issue but doing the following did the trick. I added the following files to my root directory where **libEGL.dll, libGLESv2.dll** are present ;

- avcodec-54.dll
- avformat-54.dll
- avutil-51.dll
- d3dcompiler_43.dll
- d3dx9_43.dll

Now my fonts display nicely !